# Use payload in action to specify increment item in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

In redux , i want to Use payload in action to specify increment item.
(Two button with a different age , the age will be increased when the button click.)
**But im not sure how to correctly set the clickAdd in mapDispatchToProps.**

**initialState**

```
var initialState = {
        age:15,
       age2:16
        }
```

**action creators**

```
function clickAdd(itemToIncre) {
  return {
      type: 'CLICK_ADD',
    payload:itemToIncre
  }
}
```

**// reducre**

```
function reducreForAge(state = initialState, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return 0
  }
  var age;
  switch(action.type) {
      case 'CLICK_ADD': {
          return {...state,[action.payload]:state[action.payload]+1}
      }
      default :{
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
var ButtonGroup = React.createClass({

  render() {

      const { age } = this.props;    
      const { age2 } = this.props;   

        return (
          <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}} >
          <Button  onClick={this.props.clickAdd('age')} >{age}</Button>
          <Button  onClick={this.props.clickAdd('age2')}>{age2}</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar> 
        );
      }
});
```

**mapDispatchToProps**

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return Redux.bindActionCreators({
        clickDisable: clickDisable,
         clickAdd(itemToIncre):clickAdd(itemToIncre)
  }, dispatch);
 }
```

**mapStateToProps**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {  
    return {  
        age: state.reducreForAge.age
        // anotheritem:state.reducreForAge.anotheritem
    }  
}
```

**Connection**

```
const NewButtonGroup = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonGroup);


ReactDOM.render( 
  <Provider store={store}>
    <NewButtonGroup/>
  </Provider>,
document.getElementById('button_container')
);
```

Comment: Are you connecting ButtonGroup to mapDispatchToProps ? if so, how? can you include that code also ?

Comment: thx , i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could revised your implementation of `mapDispatchToProps` by removing the call to the Redux.bindActionCreators helper, as follows:

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        clickDisable : () => dispatch(clickDisable()),
        clickAdd : (itemToIncre) => dispatch(clickAdd(itemToIncre))
    };
 }
```

This should in turn, inject the `clickDisable` and `clickAdd` functions into the props of your `<ButtonGroup/>` component. You will also need to update your ButtonGroup component as follows:

```
var ButtonGroup = React.createClass({

  render() {

      const { age } = this.props;    
      const { age2 } = this.props;   

        return (
          <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}} >

          {/* [UPDATE] add () => like so */}
          <Button onClick={() => this.props.clickAdd('age')} >{age}</Button>

          {/* [UPDATE] add () => like so */}
          <Button onClick={() => this.props.clickAdd('age2')}>{age2}</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar> 
        );
      }
});
```

Comment: You could also simplify this further by declaring `mapDispatchToProps` as an object instead of a function: `const mapDispatchToProps = {  clickDisable, clickAdd }`. The `connect` function binds action creators by default when `mapDispatchToProps` is an object.

Comment: @Tyler nice! Thanks for the tip - did not know that :-)

Comment: THx for replying , i tried the following code m then i got this error :(
 Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onClick` of type `object` supplied to `Button`, expected `function`.    

Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object